# Bolzano-Weierstrass generalized.

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, normed-spaces

Given a normed space $(X,\|\cdot\|)$, what are necessary and sufficient conditions on $X$ such that Bolzano-Weierstrass (i.e. every bounded infinite subset of $X$ admits an accumulation point) holds true?
Is this a known result? If yes, any reference will be perfect.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz%27s_lemma#Some_consequences) for the infinite dimensional case.

Comment: You mean every bounded infinite subset.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: sure, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is necessary and sufficient that $X$ is finite-dimensional.

If $X$ is finite-dimensional, then we are basically working in $(\mathbb{R}^n,\|\cdot\|_2)$, and so Bolzano-Weierstrass holds.

If Bolzano-Weierstrass holds, then the closed unitary ball is compact, and therefore $X$ [is finite-dimensional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normed_vector_space#Topological_structure).

Answer (score 3):

If $X$ is a normed vector space, the Riesz theorem asserts that close bounded sets are compact iff $X$ is of finite dimension.

You can find that and more in any good course on general topology. Try Serge Lang's course on Analysis.